# SQL working on empty date

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am using java with jdbc to connecto to a MySQL database. I need to set one of date fields as empty. This field defaults to `NULL` and if i insert an empty string, the database creates a `0000-00-00` value in cell.

I then need to use that value in a report(jasperreport) and of course it can't be like `0000-00-00`.

What I've tried to do:
Use `if..then` clause in query but i can't set it properly.
Has anyone an idea on how to get these date as empty string from the database (when I am calling jasperreport I am giving him just a sql query).

Comment: Your mysql column should be nullable, at which point I'd expect it all to work. Please show your schema and your Java code.

Comment: If you default to `NULL`, then why do you insert an empty string in the first place? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it to `NULL` in the DB, don't set it to an empty string.

Then write a select query which uses:

```
COALESCE(dt,'')
```

where `dt` is your date field.

Try this script as a test.

```
    create table test(id int, dt datetime);

    insert into test(id, dt) values (1, CURDATE());

    insert into test(id, dt) values (2, NULL);

    insert into test(id, dt) values (3, NOW());

    insert into test(id, dt) values (4, NULL);


    select
    id, coalesce(dt, '') as dt
    from
    test;
```

Comment: Ok, but i need to choose which one should be swapped. Should i use if DATE LIKE '0000-00-00' THEN COALESCE(DATE,'') , or something this way? but it is not working for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3131128 Try the script I provided, you should get it.